# Understanding out of plane principal stresses

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

Consider that the state of stress at a point is given by an element taken at that point as shown,

[image]

The principal stresses in the x-y plane are given as,

$$\sigma_{1} = {\sigma_{x} + \sigma_{y} \over 2} +
\sqrt{ \left( {\sigma_{x} - \sigma_{y} \over 2} \right)^2 + \tau_{xy}^2 }$$

$$\sigma_{2} = {\sigma_{x} + \sigma_{y} \over 2} -
\sqrt{ \left( {\sigma_{x} - \sigma_{y} \over 2} \right)^2 + \tau_{xy}^2 }$$

The sources that I'm referring to state that there will be another principal stress, the out of plane principal stress, which will be

$$\sigma_3 = 0$$

The source -

[image]

The book says there will be three principal planes and three principal stresses associated with those principal planes. In the second paragraph - "By making a more complete three-dimensional analysis, it can be shown that the three principal planes for a plane-stress element are the two principal planes already described plus the z face of the element", I'm not really sure about what 'complete three dimensional analysis' means, so this is how I analyzed -

If I take the element in the x-y, y-z and x-z plane, then for each plane (the xy, yz and xz) I would get two principal planes and two principal stresses. Which would mean there are 6 principal planes and principal stresses, in total.

$x-y$ plane

- $\sigma_{1} = {\sigma_{x} + \sigma_{y} \over 2} +
  \sqrt{ \left( {\sigma_{x} - \sigma_{y} \over 2} \right)^2 + \tau_{xy}^2 }$
- $\sigma_{2} = {\sigma_{x} + \sigma_{y} \over 2} -
  \sqrt{ \left( {\sigma_{x} - \sigma_{y} \over 2} \right)^2 + \tau_{xy}^2 }$

[image]

$y-z$ plane

- $\sigma_3 = \sigma_y$
- $\sigma_4 = 0$

[image]

$x-z$ plane

- $\sigma_5 = \sigma_x$
- $\sigma_6 = 0$

[image]

**Won't there be 6 principal planes (2 in each plane xy,yz and xz) and 6 principal stresses as opposed to what the textbook says that there are three?**

Mohr's Circle-
[image]

---

Comment: what is it exactly your question here?

Comment: You have several questions about this topic, what is wrong with the answers you already have? Or is it a textbook issue? Have you checked other books?

Comment: @NMech I've edited the question slightly, also added the source that I was referring to. My argument is that there will be 6 principal stresses, if we consider the 3D nature of the element, but the book says there will be three principal stresses.

Comment: @SolarMike This topic is giving me a hard time :P. The previous questions on the same topic, weren't about *out of plane principal stresses/ third principal stress*, so I thought of asking. I have referred to two other books, none talk about this topic in detail, they just state there is a concept like this. I'm searching for other books too however, till then if anyone could help.

Comment: What are $\sigma_4, \sigma_5, \sigma_6$? Also what are those diagonal blue lines in the sketch in the x-y plane section?  To be honest I think there is a very fundamental misunderstanding here with respect to what you are asking and how you are phrasing it.

Comment: @NMech The diagonal lines represent the principal planes in each plane - xy,yz and xz. When I see the element in the yz plane there is no shear stress along y and z and the normal stress $\sigma_z $ is zero, when I use the equations for principal stresses, one principal stress turns out to be $\sigma_y$ and the other $0$. Do you happen to remember any source where this topic of thrid principal stress is discussed?

Comment: @NMech Also added the Mohr's Circle to represent the stresses $\sigma_3$, $\sigma_4$,$\sigma_5$,$\sigma_6$

Comment: apologies but I do not know how you constructed this Mohr's circle. I believe it is not correct IMHO. I updated my answer to show you how the Mohr's circle should look like if both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are tensile for a plane stress. I am afraid the problem is that you have not yet grasped Mohr's circle and the meaning of the principal stress, so its best if you revisit those quantities. Regarding a source, that depends on what you need to understand. I would recommend Gere and Timoshenko's Mechanics of Materials as a good introductory text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Won't there be 6 principal planes (2 in each plane xy,yz and xz) and 6 principal stresses...?"**

No. A plane has two faces, xy = yx, yz = zy, xz = zy, so essentially there are only three planes - one each in the direction transverse to the axes x, y, and z, as well as three principal stresses, one each projected out of the respective principal plane.

[image]

**Mohr's circle for triaxial stresses**

Each of the circles encloses the stresses on the respective plane -
xy, yz or xz.

[image]

Comment: r13, Yes I understand that on opposite planes the stresses would be same, I'm actually talking about the principal planes obtained if I were to rotate the element about x,y,x axis. The Mohr's Circle that I added just now, would more clearly depict what I want to say..

Comment: I don't understand your sketch. What do the 3 circles represent - 3 planes?

Comment: Honestly, even I don't. Which is why I wanted to get an opinion, if it was wrong. NMech gave the correct one. I will revisit the concepts and try to connect everything.

Comment: Then the sketch is the tri-axial state (3D) of stresses as opposed to plane stresses (2D).

Comment: I was reading on the same in a book, and yes it is. Like now in 3Dwe're taking oblique planes which are inclined wrt all axes xyz. My analysis, in the question is indeed wrong.

Comment: Glad that you seem to get it. 2D stress analysis is adequate for most structural engineering problems but inadequate for disciplines such as geotechnical engineering and material science.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the principal stresses are $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3$, the principal planes involve the principal stress directions:

- $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$,
- $\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$
- and $\sigma_3$ and $\sigma_1$

For a  plane-stress condition the $\sigma_3$ is zero and $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ are in the plane of x and Y. So you don't need to consider $\sigma_3$, which makes it easier for illustration purposes and for teaching the concept.

---

Mohr's circle should look like the one below.

[image]

The one you have drawn does not make any sense. The blue with the bold outline is the stresses at plane x-y (or 1-2) if you prefer. This assumes that $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are both tensile.

Comment: It has started to make sense to me now. I'm convinced that the three mutually perpendicular planes will be the principal planes. A point on the bold circle represents the stresses on a plane inclined at some angle, where this angle is formed by rotation about the z axis. Can you tell me which plane does a point on the red circle or the purple one represent?

Comment: The smaller circle represents the plane which is **perpendicular** to the $\sigma_1$ direction, while the biggest circle is the plane **perpendicular** to the $\sigma_2$ direction.